# how to predict the density of these prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes, distribution-of-primes

if I wanna know how many prime number $p$ less than $x$, such that :

there is at least one prime number of this form$ 2Kp+1$ where $K={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}$.

for example:

if $x=1000$, then the exact value of the primes of the form $2Kp+1$, where $p>x$, and $K=1,2,.....,10$ is $395$, which very easy to predict by using hardy littlewood conjecture, and in this case it will be $$2C \frac{1000}{\ln^2 1000} \sum_{K=1}^{10} \prod_{2<q|2K} \frac{q-1}{q-2}=384$$ .

now I don't wanna predict this $395$, I wanna predict the number of the primes less than $1000$ such that:

there is at least one prime number of this form$ 2Kp+1$ where $K={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}$. which in this case equals to $162$

is there any estimate that predicts how many they are ?

Comment: Yes, the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture and its generalizations give a conjectured asympotic formula for any collection of linear polynomials, including $\{p,Kp+1\}$. See page 3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.1283.pdf) for example.

Comment: @GregMartin thank you, but is there any other researchers or books, more simpler than this one ? my knowledge does not allow me to understand papers of this level, I still undergraduate, but thank you anyway for this comment

Comment: @GregMartin let me give an example about what I need to know, Sophie germain prime is a prime $p$ where $N=2p+1$ is also prime, and there density less than $x$ is predicted to be $2C \frac{x}{ (\ln (x))^2}$, where $C$ is the hardy littlwood twin primes constant, now, if I wanna know how many primes less than $x$ where $N=4p+$ is also prime, how to do this ?

Comment: The two equations at the top of page 3 can be understood (with a little thought) without looking at anything else in the paper, and it will answer your question. (The paper talks about examples $x<n<x+x^\varepsilon$, but you can just pretend it's talking about examples $0<n<x$; the leading constant is the same, and that's what you're asking about. For all your examples, the order of magnitude is $x/\log^2x$.)

Comment: @GregMartin ok, thank you very much

Comment: @GregMartin would you please check my question again, I edited it.

Comment: You are saying that a certain set has cardinality 395 and a few lines below the same set has cardinality 162.

Comment: @lcv there are 168 prime numbers less than 1000, and  there are only 6 primes that don't have any primes of the form $2Kp+1$ , where $K=1,2,....10$, but the other primes could give us one or two or more primes of the above form,  so when I calculated them they were 395, and they were produced by the other 162 primes, actually I don't understand your question very well, but I hope that I answered you